# using getViewById() in Adapter

Tags: android, xml, list, view, adapter

I have a class extending BaseAdapter, and for the `getView()` implementation I'd like to call on a pre-existing row-template.

```
public class FeedAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> feed;
    private String state;

    public FeedAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data, String st)
    {
        super();

        this.context = context;
        feed = data;
        state = st;
    }


/**
 * IMPLEMENTED METHODS
 */
public View getView(int position, View row, ViewGroup list)
{
    //the row OBJECT!
    if (row == null){
        RelativeLayout newRow = new RelativeLayout(context);

    }
    else {
        return row;
    }
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount()
{
   //There are 2-types of View image and text.
    //but set it as 1 for now.
    return 1;
}

public long getItemId(int position)
{
    //SYNCHRONISED
    return position;
}

public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return feed.get(position);
}

public int getCount()
{
    return feed.size();
}
}
```

My problem is, I can't use `getViewById()` unless I have the parent view of the '`row-layout`' but it's kind of a Catch-22 situation if I can't even get that.

So what should I do?

Comment: The view at the top of the hierarchy in row.xml is a RelativeLayout tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `row.findViewById(R.id.etc)`  , as row is a View you can use this function. Thankyou

Comment: can you upload your layout file please

Comment: Ok, I did that Jois.

Comment: it's not RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(Context)  it's RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout)

Comment: If a row is a null pointer then it means that you are probably inserting a empty set of data

Comment: Jois u dumbass that's the 1st instance of row before recycling.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!--FOR IMAGE lookup ImageView-API for how-to input image-->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:contentDescription=""
    />

<!--STARTING WITH title-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/picture"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="20sp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/body"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```